# Cross Reference / Hyperlink with "Chapter" and Title number

Tags: microsoft-word

What I have is multiple chapters like this: "5.1 [name of chapter]"
What I want is a link like this: "Chapter 5.1"

Either I'll need the "5.1" to auto update like any REF field but WITHOUT being an actual hyperlink and then I would just add the word "Chapter" manually and turn both into a hyperlink.

Or the word "Chapter" should be part of the REF field as a constant and then I would just turn the whole 0/0/255.

However, it is important that I can change the word "Chapter" without breaking the link because the document will go through a CAD tool for translation (I know I could just manually Alt+F9 -> Find and Replace the word "Chapter" but that wouldn't be ideal)

Previously I have simple used both, a hyperlink for the word "Chapter" and a REF field for the number and they will in fact act as a single link, but the number part will not turn purple after clicking on it... and that's not very pretty... >:

(I have searched quite a bit for any information on this but couldn't find any... and I', not "field" expert, Thanks for any help in advance)

==>> okay... problem solved.. kind of...
     turns out there are 2 style templates, one is "Hyperlinks" and another is "VisitedHyperlink" so you can just turn the latter 0/0/255 and it won't look awkward when only part of a link changes color. More importantly, this still works when exported to .pdf (don't know about web publication though).
It's not ideal, I'd still rather have a "right" solution, but it works...

Comment: If only there were a "right solution." Writers have been asking MS to allow us to create useful templates for cross-references (e..g, Chap/Section N.n.n, "SectionText," on page N) for decades. The MS Word PMs are more interested in producing more flashy eye candy than adding actual utility to Word.